# How to catch the QSystemTrayIcon quit event?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QSystemTrayIcon` subclass. Inside it, I have:

```
quitAction = new QAction(tr("&Quit"), m_parent);
connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

CloseEvent doesn't work here. How can I catch this quit event? I want to save data before closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should connect your cleanup/save code to the [QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal.

> This signal is emitted when the application is about to quit the main event loop, e.g. when the event loop level drops to zero. This may happen either after a call to quit() from inside the application or when the users shuts down the entire desktop session.